# Should questions be cross-posted?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shouldn’t cross posting be allowed?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2807/shouldnt-cross-posting-be-allowed)

If there is a question that is on-topic for multiple SE sites, is it OK to cross-post to another site?

Example in mind:
Super User: [Mirror apt repository that uses .bz2 files](https://superuser.com/questions/546270/mirror-apt-repository-that-uses-bz2-files)
Server Fault: [How to mirror apt repository that uses Packages.bz2](https://serverfault.com/questions/475142/how-to-mirror-apt-repository-that-uses-packages-bz2)

These two questions were posted at the same time by the same user.

Comment: Feel free to flag any posts you discover were cross-posted.

Comment: To be honest, when I see that I usually downvote both. It's rude even on your run-in-the-mill forums, so I can't see why people would think it's okay here.

Comment: [Should I flag cross posted questions?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5972/should-i-flag-cross-posted-questions/5973#5973)

Comment: @DanielBeck Done. I flagged the post on serverfault. It was upvoted on SU so I figured it could stay there.

Comment: For reference: [Cross posting is considered abusive behavior](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu#comment181805_75012)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, choose one and only one. If after a while, you don't get a response, then you can flag it for a moderator to move it another site that it's on topic for